# PayPal error on website, how do I fix it?

Tags: drupal, paypal

I am developing a Drupal commerce website that uses Ubercart and while trying to set up the Paypal payment method, I have run into a problem.

I upgraded my Paypal account to a Business account and also created a personal test account and I configured the Ubercart module properly so users can click on the `"check out with Paypal"` button.

However, when I (as an admin or a user) click on that button to test out the checkout feature, I get this error message:

PayPal reported an error:

```
 10002: You do not have permissions to make this API call
```

I've checked to see if my email addresses have been verified, and they have.
Has anyone else run into this problem?
If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: This error is pretty clear. Did you Google the error before posting the question ? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Comment: Yes, I did. What I found is that the most likely culprit was that I didn't verify my email address with Paypal. However, I did verify it so I don't think that's the issue. So that's why I asked.

Comment: Since the error is clear - you should open a ticket with PP support and ask why did they restrict your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 ubercart paypal setting require api, username, password and signature, make sure remove certificate to get signature, I was leaving signature blank got the same error as your, after i remove certificate then get signature, it was working ok, no more error. hope it helps